# Reach another folder with \input

Tags: input, filesystem-access

How do I reach a file in another folder when using `\input`?

E.g. I have my main document `frontpage.tex` in a folder called `main` and a file `chapter1.tex` in a folder `chapters`. How do I in `frontpage.tex` reach the `chapter1.tex` with a command like the following, which I can't get working:

```
\input{..\chapters\chapter1}
```

Comment: use `/` not `\ `

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `/`  not `\`.
...........................