# How to input folders into latex?

Tags: input, thesis, filesystem-access, folders

I'm trying to compile my PhD thesis which contains three chapters.

The relevant preamble I'm using is

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{titling}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {figures/} }
```

I have a

```
main.tex
```

and I have a folder called

```
Chapters
```

which contains files

```
Intro.tex
title page.tex
```

and subfolders for each chapter of my thesis, like

```
chap1
chap2
chap3
```

I'm inputting the intro and title page files as follows

```
\section{Introduction}
\input{Chapters/Intro.tex}
```

onto the

```
main.tex
```

Now I want to do the same for each of the subfolders corresponding to each of the thesis chapters. This is important because the chapters-subfolders will contain other folders and files so I want to input them as a whole.

I have looked at the links [Input file folder](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/89247/input-file-folder)
and [Reach another folder with \input](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/84288/reach-another-folder-with-input)
But I'm not finding a solution to my exact problem.

Would appreciate any help.

Let me know if you need more information to help out.

Thanks in advance

edited to add: I tried

```
\section{Chapter 1}
\input{Chapters\chap1}
```

which did not work, to address Dai's question

Comment: Your question essentially seems to describe how you successfully use `\input` with a filename and path to source a file, what have you tried to do that hasn't worked and what did you expect it to do?

Comment: Folders are consltructs of the OS file system, which LaTeX has no access to.  You will have to read the files one at a time.  OTOH, I would use `\include` and `\includeonly` to minimize complilation time.

Comment: Reading your line `This is important ... chapter-subfolders contain other folders ...` I assume you have subdivided every chapter into sections and such. Does your chapter file have to load section files before it can by compiled? In other words: is your thesis structure a tree of nested files?

Comment: `\input{Chapters\chap1}` should be `\input{Chapters/chap1}` with  `/`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle still giving error

Comment: @alchemist yes yes exactly. tree of nested files

Comment: My advise would be to make a copy of your tree of files and then reduce the input files to just the chapter ones. You could do that by opening a chapter file and copy/paste all information from the files it calls upon into that chapter file. Then you probably end up with a set of files that are all first ones towards the main file.

Comment: @alchemist I think I'm getting a sense of what you are suggesting. Let me try this and I might have to get back to this thread to reply to you for further clarification. Thanks a ton

Comment: "still giving error" what error? with `\ ` you will get undefined  command `\chap`  error. You will not get that error with `/`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle you are far more knowledgeable than I am. Can a file used as input in main contain an input call to a second file without causing errors? My guess is that it at least would cause issues building references and citations as that would call for rerun after rerun to get every entry in their respective files before building the pdf

Comment: @alchemist yes of course you can nest input up to the depth of the input stack which is a few thousand in current systems. `\input` has no effect at all on `\ref` or `\cite`

Comment: @alchemist you should pobably delete the earlier comments as they are misleading ("My guess is that that type of nesting can't be handled b....")

Comment: [This answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/426499/11604), point 3, solve your problem?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle  I did  `\section{Chapter 1}
\input{Chapters/chap1}   `The error I'm getting is  ` LaTeX Error: File `Chapters/chap1.tex' not found.
The compiler cannot find the file you want to include. Make sure that you have uploaded the file and specified the file location correctly.
Learn more

Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed,
or enter new name. (Default extension: tex)

Enter file name: 
! Emergency stop.
<read *> 
         
l.64 \input{Chapters/chap1}
                           ^^M
*** (cannot \read from terminal in nonstop modes)`

Comment: @Fran let me try this out and get back to you

Comment: @DavidCarlisle chap1 is a folder here and definitely not a .tex file so i guess the error makes sense?

Comment: @Jan3 well yes you need to input a file `\input{Chapters/chap1/something} `

Comment: @DavidCarlisle This is working perfectly! such an elegant solution.  I loaded the tex files from the other projects and followed your suggestion and now my document looks exactly as i wanted it to. Thank you so much